# Scaling on SVG icons through CSS within a :before selector

Tags: css, svg

How can I scale SVG icons as part of a CSS :before selector?

Example:

```
a[href$=".xml"]:before {
    content: url(http://public.xxx.com/html9.svg);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

<a href="foo.xml">foo.xml</a>
```

Comment: what about content: '<img src="http://public.zioyx.com/html9.svg" width="20" height="20" />'

Comment: I clearly asked about using CSS and not for messing up my clean markup.

Comment: that is css. but instead of loading an url you load an image :(

Comment: please read my question carefully. There is a very good reason why I want to use CSS here: for not messing up existing markup - especially when the markup is not under my control. So hard to understand?

Comment: javascript isn't an option? Because as you mentioned: you cannot include markup with css. The content isn't in the DOM so you cannot change it via CSS.

Comment: I can include and scale PNG and GIF icons before the link using exactly the same way. But why not with SVG? Stay with my question and don't give me recommendation for ugly workarounds.

Comment: @JKL - Everyone here is trying to help you, and doing it for free.  Please refrain from being salty or abusive with them for trying to help.

Comment: There is nothing abusive, it's all about the ability to read a case-clear question and to give an answer. I did not ask for workarounds.

Comment: Why was this question down voted? Just because some people can not read?

Comment: Ignorant Stackoverflow bricks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

## [Fiddle with your scaled image](http://jsfiddle.net/zcvrddzo/1/)

And the relevant changes to CSS:

```
a[href$=".xml"]:before {
    content: '';
    background-image: url(http://public.xxx.com/html9.svg);
    background-size: contain;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```